# Syntax errors in C++ include file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm writing a game in c++ in microsoft visual studio 2010, yesterday I wrote a pong game and everything was fine but now the compiler telling me that there is a lot of errors for example:

```
1>w:\c++\planet escape\planet escape\room.h(25): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WorldMap'
```

And here is the Room.h file:

```
#pragma once

#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Entity.h"
#include "WorldMap.h"
#include "Link.h"

#define ROOM_W 20
#define ROOM_H 20

class Room{
private:...
public:...
};
```

When in code there is no mistakes and it sees all the classes fine.
So what can cause such mistake?

EDIT:
here is the WorldMap.h

```
#pragma once

#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include "Room.h"
#include "Player.h"

#define WORLD_W 10
#define WORLD_H 10

class WorldMap{
private:...
public:...
};
```

If when I'm runing it he cant see it then why he see it when coding?

Comment: Are you sure `WorldMap.h` defines `WorldMap` type? compiler is telling you it cannot identify the type `WorldMap`.

Comment: I think we'd need to see the WorldMap.h file to answer this question.

Comment: Since you're only using a `WorldMap*` you don't actually need to pull in the whole definition anyway - you can just add a `class WorldMap;` before your `class Room {..};` declaration. You'll need the full class before you actually use it, though.

Comment: @Rup: Bad advice, This will just hide the problem in this case. If `WorldMap.h` does not define `WorldMap` then OP might get rid of this error, but will be eventually stuck at a point where, forward declaration won't work.

Comment: You have circular includes. Don't do that.

Comment: @Als: Rup's solution is correct in this case. (In your favor, Vlad didn't show WorldMap.h until after you posted your comment.)

Comment: @David Hammen: That comment by Rup was posted before the OP posted the contents of the header and so my comment was correct based on what information was available at the time.

Comment: @Als: Did you read my parenthetic remark?

Comment: @David Hammen: I did, And Given that part in parenthesis, I don't see the reason of you informing me the first part. So to make it clear, the explicit need arises for the mention.

Comment: @Als In any case I'll stand by the suggestion of simplifying the header file if you can't understand what's going on. At the very least it'll get you past that one error and the next error might be more obvious.

Comment: @Rup: Well one should forward declare wherever possible instead of including the header is the basic rule. In this case the OP was asking a Q and that advice(when the header was not posted here) would just hide the problem and that would result in OP coming back here posting another Q. The answer we provide should be the best possible one, which solves the root of the problem not just create a loop of Q's. I would agree on your advice to OP to forward declare but after the problem is solved not before just to hide the problem. Hope I am clear enough of my reasoning if i was not before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have circular includes. Suppose you are compiling a file that has a `#include "WorldMap.h"` as the first applicable `#include` statement. The file `WorldMap.h` has that `#include "Room.h"` that is going to cause a lot of trouble. The problems start in earnest in `Room.h` at the `#include "WorldMap.h"` statement. That `#include` has no effect thanks to the `#pragma once` in `WorldMap.h`. When the compiler gets to the point of processing the main body of `Room.h`, the class `WorldMap` is neither defined nor declared.

**Addendum**
The solution is to get rid of those extraneous `#include` statements. The file `WorldMap.h` does not need to `#include` either of `Room.h` or `Player.h`. It instead needs to make forward declarations of the classes `Room` and `Player`. Similarly, you don't need all those `#include` statements in `Room.h` either.

It is in general a good idea to use forward declarations of types in your headers instead of including the file that defines the types. If the code in the header does not need to know details of the type in question, just use a forward declaration. Do not `#include` the header that defines the type.